# split select statement with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, select, parsing

i need to split any mysql select statement in its main parts: `SELECT`, `FROM`, ALL THE JOINS(if there are any), `WHERE`(if it exists),`GROUP BY`(if it exists), `HAVING`(if it exists), `ORDER BY`(if it exists), `LIMIT`(if it exists)...

i tried using regular expressions, but i'm not very good with them...
for the SELECT the regex was simple (any SELECT that comes at the begining of the string-`^SELECT`), but after that i stumbled... all i know it's that the 'FROM' must not be contained in () - which will mean it's from a subselect... and i think that all the other parts of the select (JOINS, WHERE, GROUP BY, etc) will match this rule...
but i don't know how to write such a rule... and i hope someone can help me...

for the select statement:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(audioMelodii.durata))/60) AS durataTotal, (SELECT COUNT(audioMelodii.id) FROM audioMelodii) AS nrMelodii, audioArtisti.nume AS artist, audioAlbume.*

    FROM audioAlbume

    LEFT OUTER JOIN audioMelodiiAlbume ON (audioMelodiiAlbume.idAlbum=audioAlbume.id)

    LEFT OUTER JOIN audioMelodii ON (audioMelodii.id=audioMelodiiAlbume.idMelodie)

    LEFT OUTER JOIN audioArtisti ON (audioAlbume.idArtist=audioArtisti.id)

    WHERE audioAlbume.idArtist='$idArtist'

    GROUP BY audioAlbume.id

    ORDER BY dataLansare DESC, id DESC

    LIMIT 0,10`

the result i'm looking for would be something like this:

`$STATEMENT['SELECT']='SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS (SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(audioMelodii.durata))/60) AS durataTotal, (SELECT COUNT(audioMelodii.id) FROM audioMelodii) AS nrMelodii, audioArtisti.nume AS artist, audioAlbume.*';

$STATEMENT['FROM']='FROM audioAlbume';

$STATEMENT['JOINS']='LEFT OUTER JOIN audioMelodiiAlbume ON   (audioMelodiiAlbume.idAlbum=audioAlbume.id)

    LEFT OUTER JOIN audioMelodii ON (audioMelodii.id=audioMelodiiAlbume.idMelodie)

    LEFT OUTER JOIN audioArtisti ON (audioAlbume.idArtist=audioArtisti.id)';

$STATEMENT['WHERE']="WHERE audioAlbume.idArtist='$idArtist'";`

etc...

thank you very much!
all the best!

Answer (score 2):

SQL is not a language that can be parsed with regular expressions.
You really need to use a full-blown SQL parser for this task.

See also:

- "[Regex to Extract Update Columns from a Sql Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444152/regex-to-extract-update-columns-from-a-sql-statement/444287#444287)."
- "[Parsing SQL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641119/parsing-sql-string/641150#641150)"

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this easily with regular expressions due to the recursive complexity of the SQL (sub-queries, sub-sub-queries, which can occur in several places.

Maybe if you explain your ultimate objective we could help you find a better solution.